# Best technique for testing if an event causes a trend?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, statistics, correlation, descriptive-statistics

Example - A major holiday is coming up and the frequency of a product being purchased starts increasing significantly as it gets closer to the day of the holiday. Then after the holiday, the frequency starts decreasing to "normal" non-holiday frequencies.

For that example, I would be trying to find the best technique to test if the holiday is causing any trends/significant increases in frequency compared to the normal/average purchase frequency when there isn't a holiday.

Techniques I've tested -
Linear Regression
Theil-Sen Regression
RANSAC Regression
Mann-Kendall test
Skew
Pearson Correlation

All of the techniques listed above seem to work for this to a certain extent. However, I'm not sure if its better to use a combination of these or stick with one.

Note - This would be used for descriptive purposes, not predictive. The goal is to confirm if an event creates a trend or not.

Let me know if I need to add more information or clarify anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at models for time-series? E.g AR, ARMAX.. https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/tsa.html

Comment: https://google.github.io/CausalImpact/CausalImpact.html might not be applicable but you could consider using it if the "event" doesn't impact a control series (e.g. data from a place where that day is not a holiday)